# python shuffle algorithm performance

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, shuffle

I was wondering about the time complexity of the [`shuffle` function](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) in the `random` Python library/module. Is it O(n) or is it less than that?

Is there a website that shows the time complexities of functions that belong to Python libraries?

Comment: For your second question - http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Alex: considering the only library in that list is `collections`, not quite what OP is asking for, I think.

Comment: @Wooble It's a wiki, so it may not be limited to just `collections` in the future. (Upon re-reading, it seems like this is for CPython, but at least an interesting reference. It may inspire someone to create an equivalent wiki page for `random`, and other libraries)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot shuffle a list in a completely random fashion in less than O(n).

The [implementation of `random.shuffle()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2e8b28dbc395/Lib/random.py#l276) uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), which is easily seen to be O(n).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I need my own random function (not completely random i guess)

Comment: @Saher: can you even conceive of a method of shuffling a list in place that's better than O(n)?

Comment: I haven't thought that through but what I meant is basically for my purposes for the algorithm I am writing I can just shuffle the first 4 to 5 items and choose the first one, it is not crucial.

Comment: Now that I think more about it. There is no way you can do better than O(n) since you have to encounter every list element at most once.

Comment: @Saher: If you only choose the first one, maybe all you need is `random.choice()`?